# What do we mean when we say that a muscle fiber contracts strongly?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, cell-biology, neuroscience, muscles

Sounds dumb but anyway, i heard that superfast fibers contract more strongly than fast twitch fibers. And i never thought of muscle contraction as something that has a magnitude (i thought of it as "1 or 0" meaning either contracted or not). So lets say we have two fibers, the same length and thickness, if one contracts more than the other does that simply mean that it becomes shorter ?

Comment: i'm no expert but try looking up animations on youtube of muscle contraction that may help, here is one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GneonFlcZG8